# Unable to store binary in Elasticsearch through python REST API

Tags: elasticsearch, binaryfiles

I have created a Elaticsearch index like

> PUT new_index_blob
> > {
> >   "mappings": {
> >     "properties": {
> >       "name": {
> >         "type": "text"
> >       },
> >       "blob": {
> >         "type": "binary",
> >         "store": true
> >       }
> >     }
> >   }
> > }

When I am trying to store a Base64 encoded binary value from Dev Tools of Kibana like below , it working fine

> PUT new_index_blob/_doc/1
> {
> "name": "Test",
> "blob": "U29tZSBiaW5hcnkgYmxvYg=="
> }

I am able to get/search the same from Dev Tools

```
GET /new_index_blob/_source/1
```

But when I am trying to store the same using python REST API its not working , not giving any error too , below code snippet

```
path = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\My_Folder\\"
name= "100.97.16.31_2020_Jul_17_09_14.zip" # 53 Mb
zip_file_path = os.path.join(path, name)
elastic_url= "http://%s/%s/%s"%(
  "localhost:9200",
  "new_index_blob",
  "_doc/2"
)
try:
    data = open(zip_file_path, "rb").read()
    encoded = str(base64.b64encode(data))
    upload_data={}

    upload_data["name"]=name
    upload_data["blob"]=encoded
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))

try:
    resp_elastic = requests.put(
            elastic_url,
            headers=headers,
            data=json.dumps(upload_data),
            verify=False
    )
    print("ES Entry completed for {}".format(name))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

What is the mistake I am doing . Also even after inserting it from Dev Tools the Doc count is showing 0 , is it expected for **datatype binary with store true**

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: I have fixed it now , it was byte string conversion issue. ES was expecting base64 encoded string and I was sending bytes .

Comment: `encoded = str(base64.b64encode(data).decode("utf-8") )` fixed the issue for me